# Can MailKit be used for "Contact Me" form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-core-1.0, mailkit

I'm new to web programming and I am making a website using ASP.NET Core. I am trying to create a standard "contact me" page where the user enters in a name, email, subject and message. ASP.NET Core has yet to have `System.Net.Mail`, so I can't use that.

I saw that MailKit could be used to send emails, but am unable to figure out how to use it for a contact page. I know using this code

```
 using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
            client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

            // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
            // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

            client.Send (message);
            client.Disconnect (true);
```

I can send an email using my SMTP server, but obviously I want the functionality of users using the site to be able to send an email to me. Is there a way to use MailKit for this, or do I need to find another solution? Thanks.

Edit: 
This is the code I have that successfully sends an email, but it always says that it was sent from me to me.

```
public IActionResult SendEmail(Contact contact)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(contact.Name, contact.Email));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("myname", "myemail"));
        emailMessage.Subject = contact.Subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = contact.Message };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587); 
            client.Authenticate("myemail", "myemailpassword");
            client.Send(emailMessage);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MailKit can be used for this purpose.

The problem you are seeing is because outlook.com is replacing your From header with your email address (it's a "feature" of outlook.com when you login via SMTP).

You might be able to sort of work around this by setting the ReplyTo to the user's address (so you can reply to them).

Or you could try setting the From to the user's address and setting the Sender to your address (not sure if this will work).

Comment: I tried setting the Sender to my address and that doesn't seem to work. I decided to try and use the yahoo smtp server instead, but now it is giving me an error saying my "from address" is not verified. Does it matter that the "from" is outlook and the stmp server is yahoo? If I hard code the yahoo email into the "from" section it works.

Comment: This is a feature of the SMTP server to minimize spam. There's not much I can suggest other than trying another server.